# 4 people are taking the bus for a maximum of 9 stops

Tags: probability

4 people are on a bus. There are 9 stops left on the trip, and the 4 people will get off on these stops. All 4 persons will select a stop randomly, and every stop can be selected multiple times.

A) What is the probability that 2 people get off on the same stop?

B) What is the probability that every person will get off on different stops?

Pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (A), consider the probability that all 4 people will get off at different stops. This can be done in 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 ways (the first person has 9 stops to choose from, the second person has the remaining 8 stops to choose from, etc.) Divide this by the total number of possibilities (9^4 unique ways of the 4 people getting off). Then $\frac{9*8*7*6}{9^4}$ gives you the probability that all 4 people will get off at different stops. Then $1 - \frac{9*8*7*6}{9^4}$ gives you the probability that at least two people will get off at the same stop.